# R - using rselenium, how to navigate through drop-down directory

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to use rselenium to upload a CSV file to a website. My last two lines of code are below, which I use to click on an 'upload' button on the website, prompting the website to drop-down a window with my directories, similar to finder, that I can navigate through to select which file I'd like to upload. The code that prompts the drop-down:

```
upload_CSV_link = remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "button.dk-btn.dk-btn-success.dk-btn-icon.pull-right")
upload_CSV_link$clickElement()
```

For clarity, this is essentially the same drop-down that you would get when clicking save as in a microsoft word / excel document. The difficult aspect of this drop-down is that I cannot inspect elements in the drop-down, making it more difficult to navigate to the correct directory / select the correct file. Has anybody experienced this issue before?

Thanks,

Comment: if i could find someway to click the search box, type the filename in, and then click the (only) file that appears, that would do it for me.

Comment: Don't use comments to clarify, use [edit].

Comment: I feel like you should be able to do this via a javascript command submitted with RSelenium